# MathJax formula has extraneous line breaks on the user profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, mathjax, latex

MathJax formulas can have extraneous line breaks on the user profile page. An example from https://math.stackexchange.com/users/24265/franck-dernoncourt?tab=topactivity:

[image]

It was tested with Chrome on a [Google Pixel 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_6) running [Android 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11).

Comment: Repro here on Galaxy A41 with Android 11, Chrome. Not as dramatic as with yours, and a slight variation as the break appears in a different place. (Stable at different zooms).