# Find questions with the longest titles

Tags: support, data-explorer, title

I want to find the list of questions on a site that have the longest titles.

The purpose is testing design elements that might break or have layout problems if the title is too long. It's also an interesting query by itself, but searching visually through the questions listing is just too frustrating.

Comment: Longest titles by character count or width?

Comment: @Laurel what do you mean by width? the data-explorer only knows character counts since the rendering is done by the browser client-side and depends on your fonts, etc...

Comment: A long time ago, the title character limit used to be 250 instead of 150, so you might find some posts that use longer titles from the time they were allowed.

Comment: Note that sometimes question titles with MathJax formula may cause issues https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378009/178179

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's your query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1610322/1964929/longest-post-titles). You can adjust the number in `SELECT TOP 100` to change the number of rows returned. Note that the ordering among posts tied for title length is arbitrary, and changes from execution to execution.

SQL:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 Id as [Post Link], Title
FROM Posts
ORDER BY LEN(Posts.Title) DESC
```