# Font size in the Stacks Editor when editing Markdown is too small; please increase it to match current editor

Tags: feature-request, markdown, accessibility, stacks-editor

I've been using the Stacks Editor's Markdown preview mode, and I've found the font size to be a bit too small, which makes the text harder to read for me.

Here's how it looks like in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10, at 125% DPI:

[image: Lower font size in Stacks Editor]

On the other hand, the current editor has a much larger font size, which means it's a lot easier for me to read when distanced from my screen:

[image: Larger font size in current editor]

Can the font size of the Markdown view of the Stacks Editor please be increased to match that of the current editor, to make it more accessible?

I'd also like to address a counterpoint that a smaller font size makes it so more text can show in the same space, reducing the space required: first, I think readability and accessibility are more important; second, the editor can be freely expanded if one wants to view more, and third, the Stacks Editor by default loads much more expanded compared to the current editor.

The latest question regarding the Stacks Editor [is no longer being monitored for new answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode-is-now-available?noredirect=1#comment1282881_382236), and a staff member said requests should be posted as new questions (until the next announcement).

See also this [related issue I filed on GitHub about accessibility with the Stacks Editor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/236).